# Operation of type Placeholder X is not supported on the TPU. Execution will fail if this op is used in the graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, word-embedding, tpu, bert-language-model

I am running text classification task using BERT on TPU.
I have used different tutorials to run my experiments as [1](https://hackernoon.com/enterprise-af-solution-for-text-classification-using-bert-9fe2b7234c46), [2](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/bert_finetuning_with_cloud_tpus.ipynb), [3](https://medium.com/@ranko.mosic/googles-bert-nlp-5b2bb1236d78), and [4](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-research/bert/blob/master/predicting_movie_reviews_with_bert_on_tf_hub.ipynb).
My only difference with the second example was that my dataset was not one of the predefined datasets in Bert processors, so I had to load it and preprocess it myself. Also, I wanted to make some changed in the `create_model` so I had to write it down as follow:

```
 def create_model(is_training, input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, labels,
             num_labels, bert_hub_module_handle):
 tags = set()
  if is_training:
    tags.add("train")
  bert_module = hub.Module(bert_hub_module_handle, tags=tags, trainable=True)
  bert_inputs = dict(
      input_ids=input_ids,
      input_mask=input_mask,
      segment_ids=segment_ids)
  bert_outputs = bert_module(
      inputs=bert_inputs,
      signature="tokens",
      as_dict=True)


  output_layer = bert_outputs["pooled_output"]

  hidden_size = output_layer.shape[-1].value

  output_weights = tf.get_variable(
      "output_weights", [num_labels, hidden_size],
      initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02))

  output_bias = tf.get_variable(
      "output_bias", [num_labels], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

  with tf.variable_scope("loss"):
    if is_training:
      # I.e., 0.1 dropout
      output_layer = tf.nn.dropout(output_layer, keep_prob=0.9)

    logits = tf.matmul(output_layer, output_weights, transpose_b=True)
    logits = tf.nn.bias_add(logits, output_bias)
    probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits, axis=-1)
    log_probs = tf.nn.log_softmax(logits, axis=-1)

    one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, depth=num_labels, dtype=tf.float32)

    per_example_loss = -tf.reduce_sum(one_hot_labels * log_probs, axis=-1)
    tf_loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=one_hot_labels,
    logits=log_probs,
    weights=1.0)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(per_example_loss)

    return (tf_loss, loss, per_example_loss, logits, probabilities)
```

When I run the code, with my `create_model` I see many errors while there is not problem with the training and everything goes well, but I'm not sure whether: 1. the model is using TPU or not because of the following errors, 2. the model is using Bert and fine tune it because of the following errors for all of the `create_model` function. Any idea?
Here is the error ( millions of times for all functions):

`Operation of type Placeholder X is not supported on the TPU. Execution will fail if this op is used in the graph.`

Comment: The error looks weird. After your own pre-processing, did you manage to convert `input_ids`, ` input_mask` to dense vectors and save to tensorflow.Example? That is, do you have something like https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/run_classifier.py#L509, the `file_based_input_fn_builder`? I think if you use this (with `tf.dataset`) you do not need to use a "placeholder".

Comment: Did you solve the problem in the end?